# Python: What is the most efficient / fastest way to unpack the following dataframe to a matrix?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following grid(actually a dataframe):

```
params = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(alpha, gamma) for alpha in np.linspace(0,1,10) for gamma in np.linspace(0,2,10)]), 
                      columns = ['alpha','gamma'])
```

Then I use `apply`

```
params['res'] = params.apply(lambda row: func(x=params['alpha'],y=params['gamma'],axis=1)
```

How do I unpack the above into a matrix/dataframe below?

```
pd.DataFrame(elements of params['res'], 
             index = np.linspace(0,1,10), 
             columns = np.linspace(0,2,10))
```

Comment: IIUC you want to make a 10 by 10 numpy 2d array/matrix from the `res` column you create?

Comment: Yes. Row index will be the alpha range and the column name is the gamma range .

Comment: What is func here? Can you provide the data you're expecting in res

Comment: Actually, the function doesn’t matter. You can assign 0 values to the column res.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first trasform the `res` Series to a numpy array, then use the `reshape` method:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(params['res'].to_numpy().reshape(10,10), 
                         index = np.linspace(0,1,10), 
                         columns = np.linspace(0,2,10))
```

Using a smaller size example:

```py
# Simulating res
res = np.random.randint(0,10, 9)

res
array([9, 3, 5, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 6])

res.reshape(3,3)
array([[9, 3, 5],
       [9, 3, 1],
       [4, 0, 6]])
```

If this is not your expected result, you can traspose it:

```py
res.reshape(3,3).T
array([[9, 9, 4],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [5, 1, 6]])
```

Comment: So, reshape method rearrange the elements of red by rows first and then columns ? Am I correct ?

Comment: I am adding an example of reshape

Comment: It's not really `reshape` in this case.

Comment: Oh I see what you did there! He wants indexes and column to be `alpha` and `gamma`. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `pivot`:

```
params.pivot(index='alpha', columns='gamma', values='res')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question only ask the fastest way to make a 10 by 10 numpy 2d array/matrix from the res column, then I think this solution is the one:

```
params.res.values.reshape(10,10)
```